# One bundle identifier in Crashlytics for multiple apps

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have a whitelabeled app and every customer's app has its own unique bundle identifier. This causes Crashlytics to flood with different apps which potentially could have the same crash report. I would like to have it all grouped under one app, so it's easier to maintain.

I know there's a solution for Android (https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/6188014), but couldn't find anything for iOS.

Does anybody know if this is possible for iOS and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently, there isn't a way to do this on iOS for Fabric. I'll let the team know you'd like to see it added in.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would love to see this option!

Comment: Noted and heard :)

Comment: Any changes on this Mike Bonnel?

Comment: No changes @PaulvanRoosendaal and currently it's not on our immediate roadmap to add in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, and I've confirmed with testing today that Crashlytics forces me to have a separate app in their system for each of my customers. I suspect with Firebase/Google integration this will not change as they'll be offering a complete app framework (just as the transition from Xamarin Insights -> HockeyApp -> Microsoft Mobile Center). I reviewed the alternatives today; Raygun.com has had long-standing support for Xamarin and the only association between your app and Raygun is a text key, and it works with or without the dSYM files. So far so good!

Comment: John-Daniel from Raygun here. Couple of notes: In the scenario that Paul has, I'd use Raygun's custom tags, to tag each white label customer. You can pivot all data that way. Second, to your point about dsyms, while Raygun will work without it, if the errors occur below the Xamarin layer, then you'll still want to provide the dsym so we can symbolify the lower level errors for you. I hope that helps!